# PDF to Image conversion using iText in java

Tags: java, itext

I have a requirement to convert PDF document to images and store it as a JPEG format in one physical location. I want to make this conversion using **iText** only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864726/convert-a-pdf-file-to-single-jpeg

Comment: What are you tried? What are the errors / problems?

Comment: Unfortunately, rendering PDFs to images is outside the scope of iText. You'll need another product; for instance JPedal: http://www.idrsolutions.com/java-pdf-library/

Answer (score 4):

`iText` can't help you much. You need a renderer to do that.

You can use [JPedal](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpedal/) Open Source library .

Answer (score 4):

iText will not help you much to convert pdf to image. You can use **pdfbox** to convert pdf to image. For more information click [here](http://gal-levinsky.blogspot.it/2011/11/convert-pdf-to-image-via-pdfbox.html)